# Refactoring a class method to an interface in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

In a reports module, there is an email service that I would want to refactor so I can use it as a general purpose email service. Actually, i have a requirement to send emails to users when they want to reset their password so that's the main reason for refactoring.

```
public class EmailService{

    public Email buildEmail(ReportRequest reportRequest){
    //build email using ReportRequest object here
    }

}

@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Email implements Serializable {
    private String subject;
    private String text;
    private String recipientEmail;
    private String senderEmail;

}
```

The way I had refactor this is like this:

I created an interface called EmailService that has a buildEmail() method. I was thinking that whichever class that implements this will have a different way of constructing/building its email.

```
public interface EmailService{
    public Email buildEmail();
}

public class ReportEmailService implements EmailService{
   public Email buildEmail(){}
}

public class PasswordEmailService implements EmailService{
   public Email buildEmail(){}
}
```

My question now is, since building the email will utilize different objects (e.g. ReportRequest or another object like AccountInfo), what would be the best way of passing the required object into the buildEmail()?

What I did here was to create another method and create a class variable for the required object that will be utilized in the buildEmail().

Basically, now it looks like this:

```
public class ReportEmailService implements EmailService{
   private ReportRequest reportRequest;

   public void sendEmail(ReportRequest reportRequest){
       this.reportRequest = reportRequest;
       Email email = buildEmail();
   }

   public Email buildEmail(){
       #build email now using the report request object. 
   }
}

 public class PasswordResetEmailService implements EmailService{
   private AccountInfo accountInfo;

   public void sendEmail(AccountInfo accountInfo){
       this.accountInfo= accountInfo;
       Email email = buildEmail();
   }

   public Email buildEmail(){
       #build email now using the account info object. 
   }
}
```

I feel that my approach is somewhat awkward. I might have missed something basic here in terms of design pattern and refactoring, so what could be the best approach in refactoring this? Or how can the buildEmail() have access to the specific object that it needs when it builds the email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics can help you solve this.

Declare the interface like so:

```
interface EmailService<T> {
    Email buildEmail(T t);
}
```

and your implementations this way:

```
class ReportEmailService<ReportRequest> implements EmailService {
    Email buildEmail(ReportRequest req) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The "Generics" part is what is between the chevrons (`<T>`), it acts as a placeholder for a type that you define later for each implementation.

Books about Domain Driven Design define that a service is a singleton, so in most cases you shouldn't create multiple instances of the same service.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement multiple email services, or you could delegate to the argument.

```
interface EmailService {
    boolean send(EmailFactory arg)

    interface EmailFactory {
        Email buildEmail();
    }
}
```

Then, your `ReportRequest` and `AccountInfo` classes can implement the `EmailFactory`, or even better, you create an adaptor class which knows how to `buildEmail` for each type...

```
class ReportRequestEmailFactory implements EmailFactory {
    private ReportRequest report;
    public Email buildEmail() {
        return ...
    }
}

class AccountInfoEmailFactory implements EmailFactory {
    private AccountInfo account;
    public Email buildEmail() {
        return ...
    }
}
```

In this way you implement a single `EmailService` which knows only how to send emails. And you implement specific wrappers/adaptors for each type of thing that you want to send as an email.

This is also easily extended to allow different types of emails for different domain classes, like `FullDetailsAccountInfoEmailFactory` and `SummaryAccountInfoEmailFactory`.

Bonus points, perhaps, if you start to use standard types

```
class EmailService implements Consumer<Email> {
    public void accept(Email email) {
        // TODO: send email
    }
}
class AccountInfoEmailTransformer implements Function<AccountInfo,Email> {
    public Email apply(AccountInfo t) {
        // TODO: transform AccountInfo to Email
        return ...
    }
}
```

Then you can do things like

```
EmailService emailer = ...
AccountInfoEmailFunction transformer = ...

List<AccountInfo> accounts = ...

accounts.stream().map(transformer).forEach(emailer);
```